# vim line number does weird things on lines starting with an 8

Tags: vim

I have some commands set up that run the test under my current cursor position. using the command `rails test <filename>:<linenumber>`. I execute this command through
`exec '!rails test %:'.line('.')` which works fine in most situations. However, for some reason when the line number starts with an `8` it behaves weirdly.

when testing with the command `:exec '!echo "%:'.line('.').'"'` i get the following outputs

```
line  7 -> test.txt:7
line  8 -> test.txt
line  9 -> test.txt:9
line 79 -> test.txt:79
line 80 -> test.txt0
line 89 -> test.txt9
line 90 -> test.txt:90
```

This pattern repeats for the 800s as well.
Am i missing something obvious?

EDIT: As someone in the comments suggested i [posted my question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/38093/vim-line-number-does-weird-things-on-lines-starting-with-an-8) on the vi-stackexchange.

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This command:

```
:exec '!echo "%:'.line('.').'"'
```

is handled in several steps from the inside to the outside:

1. `line('.')` is evaluated to `8`,
2. `'!echo "%:'.'8'.'"'` is evaluated to `'!echo "%:8"'`
3. `'!echo "%:8"'` is parsed by Vim before being sent to `:execute`, in order to expand various special characters as explained in `:help cmdline-special`. The "problem" (more like "powerful feature" if you ask me) is that the expansion takes into account `:help filename-modifiers` and `:8` is a legit filename modifier:

   > :8 Converts the path to 8.3 short format (currently only on MS-Windows). Will act on as much of a path that is an existing path.

   After expansion, `'!echo "%:8"'` looks like `'!echo "test.txt"'` because no conversion was performed. If the number is `80`, you get `test.txt0` because the file name is left as-is and then there's that trailing `0`. And so on for `test.txt00`, etc.
4. `!echo "test.txt"` (or `!echo "test.txt0"`, or `!echo "test.txt00"`, etc.) is finally executed.

In order to avoid that unwanted expansion, you should evaluate the file name and the line number separately:

```
'!rails test '.expand('%').':'.line('.')
```